# Regular expression to select all characters except letters or digits

Tags: regex

I have this regular expression:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]
```

I am trying to select any characters except digits or letters, but when I test  this, only the first character is matched.

When I use

```
[a-zA-Z0-9]
```

the matches are correctly digits and letters. I need to negate it, but the `^` does not work.

Comment: `^` must be inside character group to negate, e.g. `[^a-zA-Z]`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Negate characters in Regular Expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1763071/negate-characters-in-regular-expression)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Below is a quick summary of regexps and how you can group together a query set using the commands below. In your case place the `^` inside the `[a-zA-Z0-9]` to achieve the desired result.

```
  .   Single character match except newline
  "." Anything in quotations marks literally
  A*  Zero or more occurrences of A
  A+  One or more occurrences of A
  A?  Zero or one occurrence of A
  A/B Match A only if followed by B
  ()  series of regexps grouped together
  []  Match any character in brackets
  [^] Do not match any character in brackets
  [-] Define range of characters to match
  ^   Match beginning of new line
  $   Match end of a line
  {}  Cardinality of pattern match set
  \   Escapes meta-characters
  |   Disjunctive matches, or operation match
```

Answer (score 5):

Putting the `^` at start of your expression means "search from the beginning of the string". You need to put it inside the square brackets to make it a negation.

```
[^a-zA-Z0-9]
```

Comment: what about spanish alphabets like ñ

Comment: @BraveNewMath lots of existing stack overflow questions already answer your question.

Answer (score 3):

To negate you must put the `^` inside the brackets:

```
[^a-zA-Z0-9]
```