# Select-String: match a string only if it isn't preceded by a specific character

Tags: regex, powershell, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds, select-string

I have a list of files that contain either of the two strings:

"`stuff`" or "`;stuff`"

I'm trying to write a PowerShell Script that will return only the files that contain "`stuff`". The script below currently returns *all* the files because obviously "`stuff`" is a substring of "`;stuff`"

For the life of me, I cannot figure out how to only matches file that contain "`stuff`", without a preceding `;`

```
Get-Content "C:\temp\list\list.txt" |
  Where-Object { Select-String -Quiet -Pattern "stuff" -SimpleMatch $_ }
```

Note: `C:\temp\list\list.txt` contains a list of file paths that are each passed to `Select-String`.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: How about a regex? `Select-String -Pattern '[^;]stuff'`

Comment: If your goal is to select patterns that are `stuff` literally and not `;stuff`, you can use a negated set (don't use `-SimpleMatch`): `-Pattern '[^;]stuff'`

Comment: using `[^;]stuff` produces zero results and I'm not sure why as this does make sense. After playing around `^stuff` does produce the result that I am looking for, but I still don't know why one works vs. the other.

Comment: An alternative is `[^;]?`, but a negative lookbehind is the right tool for the job.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1: `[^;]?stuff` is tempting too, but also doesn't work:  `';stuff' -match '[^;]?stuff'` -> `$true`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot perform the desired matching with *literal* substring searches (`-SimpleMatch`).

Instead, **use a *regex* with a *negative look-behind assertion*** (`(?<!..)`) to rule out `stuff` substrings preceded by a `;` char.: `(?<!;)stuff`

Applied to your command:

```
Get-Content "C:\temp\list\list.txt" | 
  Where-Object { Select-String -Quiet -Pattern '(?<!;)stuff' -LiteralPath $_ }
```

---

**Regex pitfalls:**

- It is tempting to use `[^;]stuff` instead, using a **negated (`^`) character set (`[...]`**) (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1763582/45375)); however, this will *not* work as expected if `stuff` appears at the *very start of a line*, because a character set - whether negated or not - only matches an actual *character*, not the start-of-the-line *position*.
- It is then tempting to apply `?` to the negated character set (for an *optional* match - 0 or 1 occurrence): `[^;]?stuff`. However, that would match a string containing `;stuff` again, given that `stuff` is *technically* preceded by a "0-repeat occurrence" of the negated character set; thus, `';stuff' -match '[^;]?stuff'` yields `$true`.

Only a look-behind *assertion* works properly in this case - see [regular-expressions.info](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

Answer (score 1):

To complement @mklement0's answer, I suggest an alternative approach to make your code easier to read and understand:

```
#requires -Version 4
@(Get-Content -Path 'C:\Temp\list\list.txt').
    ForEach([IO.FileInfo]).
    Where({ $PSItem | Select-String -Pattern '(?<!;)stuff' -Quiet })
```

This will turn your strings into objects (`System.IO.FilePath`) and utilizes the array functions [`ForEach`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_arrays?view=powershell-5.1#foreach) and [`Where`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_arrays?view=powershell-5.1#where) for brevity/conciseness.  Further, this allows you to pipe the paths *as objects* which will be accepted by the `-Path` parameter into `Select-String` to make it more understandable (I find long lists of parameter sets difficult to read).

Comment: Thanks. I was initially playing with file-info input as well, though  in the end I think simply changing `$_` to `-LiteralPath $_` would have made the OP's code clearer. You may have chosen the `@(...)` for conceptual clarity, but let me point that `.ForEach()` and `.Where()` work even on scalars.

Comment: @mklement0 do they?  I've had issues with that assumption where exceptions were thrown for being non-arrays, but that might've been some edge case or incorrect usage

Comment: AFAIK, yes: `'foo'.foreach({ "[$_]" })`, `(1).foreach({ "[$_]" })`. Can you give an example where it doesn't work?

Comment: @mklement0 Not off the top of my head.  It bit me once so I moved to using `@( )` wherever I need or want `ForEach`/`Where`

Comment: I see; `@(...)` certainly doesn't hurt, but it would be good to know whether use on scalars can be relied upon; if you do find an exception, please file an issue on GitHub.

Answer (score -1):

The example code posted won't actually run, as it will look at each line as the `-Path` value.

What you need is to get the content, select the string you're after, then filter the results with `Where-Object`

```
Get-Content "C:\temp\list\list.txt" | Select-String -Pattern "stuff" | Where-Object {$_ -notmatch ";stuff"}
```

You could create a more complex regex if needed, but depends on what your result data from your files looks like

Comment: `list.txt` is a _list of files_ whose content should be searched. Your command searches the list itself instead.