# Using Regex in javascript to find all occurrance all up to but excluding the particular string

Tags: javascript, regex

So basically given this string `iiisdoso` i want to extract all the part of the string before but excluding the letter `o`. 
So basically `iiisd` and `s`.
I current just have

```
const data = "iiisdoso"
const regex = /(.*?)o/g

console.log(data.match(regex))
```

but this result includes the o in but my goal is return results up to but excluding `o`

Comment: Look up `[]` in regex. It is called [character classes](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html#classes)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Negate characters in Regular Expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1763071/negate-characters-in-regular-expression)

Comment: in this case i would suggest doing a split on "o" or whatever other condition you may have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentioned in the comments you can achieve this with negations and character classes:

```
const data = "iiisdoso"
const regex = /([^o]+)/g

console.log(data.match(regex))
```

This will give you the desired result

```
["iiisd", "s"]
```

But this does match any string with no "o" after it too! To avoid this, you need to use

```
const regex = /([^o]+)o/g
```

In this case the "o" is included in the matches and must be deleted for each string the result-array - e.g. with

```
mymatch.replace('o','')
```

Interesting: If you use

```
const regex = /([^o]*)/g
```

The result is

```
["iiisd", "", "s", "", ""]
```

This is something I don't understand. Well - I understand that an empty string matches the regex too and can be placed right before the "o". But why do we get a third empty string at the very end?

Comment: the third empty string at the very end matches the empty string after the "o" at the end of the whole string

Comment: Good point - you are right. This gave me the idea that my first solution will match any string without subsequent "o" too. I edited my answer and added this point.